# Screensaver lost functions since High Sierra upgrade, can't wake screen with keyboard

Tags: sleep-wake, high-sierra, screensaver

Since the High Sierra upgrade, I no longer can wake my screen with the "esc" key or by pressing any key or moving my mouse. I have to click the mouse a couple of times to wake the screen.

Also, my photos screensaver no longer will respond to backward or forward in order to scroll through pictures while the screensaver is on. Is there a tweak for this so I can get back these functions that I used daily with Sierra? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try turning ON the following setting:

> System Preferences > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces: ON (checked)

*Then log out and log back in again for it to take effect.*

Not really a solution—more of a workaround—since maybe you *want* that setting disabled.  But I guess it might be a bug in High Sierra, because I don't think the Mission Control settings should affect the screensaver...

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I have found by accident that if I move the mouse and then click it elsewhere on the screen while the screensaver is running, it will allow a left-arrow or right-arrow to scroll through the pictures. So my accidental work around has been the best thing for now.